# Google Games Services works okay, but Russian players can't connect

Tags: google-play-games

I have an issue with a few games that I made.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menesapps.senet2

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menesapps.ur

(Don't know if I can give these links, for if not, don't hesitate to moderate).

I use Google Play Games Services for Unity for leaderboards, achievements and saved games and it works fine. But I often get emails or reviews from people from Russia saying that they can't connect to the game and after checking with them, there is no issues with the app. 
GPGS do everything correctly but it fails to connect in the end (see screenshot).
Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting).

> If you are unable to sign players into your game, first make sure that you have followed the instructions to [create your client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) and [configure the games services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring). If you still encounter sign-in errors, check the following items to make sure that your game is set up correctly.

And, for additional insights, you may also see this [GitHub post](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1834).

Comment: Login works fine for most players though. If it was badly configured, more people would have issues. At this time, only some people from Russia are unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is related to the Play store or Play Services vs. a programming question.

I'd suggest contacting Google Play developer support.  On the Play console, click the questionmark (help) icon on the top right and then at the bottom "Contact us".

Comment: I will try that, thank you. I posted here because one of the pages from Google sent me to this website.

Comment: Support answered me with an automatic email telling me they don't "support user-facing issues" and to send my users a link to tell them how to connect.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your games isnt publised for Russian country. Check you google developer console.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked and the game is published for all countries, Russia included.